# Ubuntu16.04のpreseedでパーティションが意図通りに切れない理由について

Tags: ubuntu

【質問】
Ubunt16.04のpreseedでパーティション意図通りに切れないため、お知恵を拝借できませんでしょうか？

【やりたいこと】
/ (ルート)を 300GB確保したい。ファイルシステムはXFS。

【やったこと】

```
boot-root :: \
  500 50 500 xfs \
  $primary{ } $bootable{ } \
  method{ format } format{ } \
  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs } \
  mountpoint{ /boot } \
  . \
1024 512 1024 linux-swap \
  lv_name{ swap } \
  method{ swap } format{ } \
  $lvmok{ } \
  . \
321504 10000 321504 xfs \
  lv_name{ root } \
  method{ lvm } format{ } \
  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs } \
  mountpoint{ / } \
  $lvmok{ } \
  . \
```

【結果】
ディスクの最大容量でパーティションが切られてしまう。

【気づいたこと】

```
  500 50 500 xfs \
  $primary{ } $bootable{ } \
  method{ format } format{ } \
  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs } \
  mountpoint{ /boot } \
  . \
1024 512 1024 linux-swap \
  lv_name{ swap } \
  method{ swap } format{ } \
  $lvmok{ } \
  . \
321504 10000 321504 xfs \
  lv_name{ root } \
  method{ lvm } format{ } \
  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs } \
  mountpoint{ / } \
  $lvmok{ } \
  . \
535520 20000 535520 xfs \
  lv_name{ docker } \
  method{ lvm } format{ } \
  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs } \
  mountpoint{ /hoge } \
  $lvmok{ } \
  .
```

別のパーティションを作成するとルートパーティションは上記の通りきちんと300GB確保されます。
(ただし、最後に追加した dockerという名前のlvmの/hoge領域は 535520 という値をいれているにもかかわらず、-1を入れたときと同じ最大値で作成されてしまいます)

どうやら、一番最後に追加したパーティションの容量は常に最大容量になってしまうのですがこれを回避する方法はありませんでしょうか？（指定した容量でパーティションを切りたい）

【環境】
Ubuntu16.04
HDD 1TBのディスク1本

Comment: お気付きの通り最後のパーティションはディスクの空き容量全体を使用します。
ですので、余分に1つパーティションを作ってから後で削除してはいかがでしょう？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！最後のパーティションが空き容量全体を使用してしまうのはUbuntu16.04でpreseedを利用した場合の「仕様」なのでしょうか？

Comment: [ubuntuのpreseedはpartman-autoのサポートに準じる](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs04.html)ので、つまり[partman-autoのアルゴリズム](http://ftp.dc.volia.com/pub/debian/preseed/partman-auto-recipe.txt)でパーティションされるのですが、この仕様上(5. LIMITATIONS)で最低1つは空き領域全体を指定するパーティションが必要です。

Comment: わかりやすい説明ありがとうございます！理解できました。

Comment: 回答として改めて投稿しておきました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

お気付きの通り最後のパーティションはディスクの空き容量全体を使用します。
ですので、余分に1つパーティションを作ってから後で削除してはいかがでしょう？

[ubuntuのpreseedはpartman-autoのサポートに準じます。](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs04.html)
つまり[partman-autoのアルゴリズム](http://ftp.dc.volia.com/pub/debian/preseed/partman-auto-recipe.txt)でパーティションされるわけなのですが、
この仕様上(5. LIMITATIONS)で最低1つは空き領域全体を指定するパーティションが必要です。
その穴埋めとして最後のパーティションが空き領域全体を指定するようになります。